# netdom query pdc fails on Domain controller

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

One of the domain child controller fails when I run `netdom query/D:abc.example.com PDC`.

The output is:

```
C:\Users\username>netdom query /D:abc.example.com PDC
The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

The command failed to complete successfully.
```

What are the possible reasons for that error?

What DNS records should exists for it work correctly?

Currently I've setup DNS records for the following:

```
abc.example.com   -> 10.10.10.10
host-001-dc-child -> 20.20.20.20
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the domain DNS name is in fact `abc.example.com` and you're not referring to an actual host.

You don't manually allocate internal DNS entries for your domain root, if that's what you've done.

The way that AD creates a DNS entry for abc.example.com is by creating an A record for each DC in the domain root with a blank hostname (or an "@", depending on how you look at them).

So when you do an `nslookup abc.example.com`, you should see something like - one address for each DC:

```
Name:    abc.example.com
Addresses:  10.4.0.67
      10.4.0.12
      10.4.0.11
      10.4.0.139
```

These root A records are added by the `netlogon` process on each DC when you reboot it (or restart the service)

How long has this domain been around? The DNS zone should have been created and the records (A, SOA and SRV) created as soon as you DCpromoed the first DC. If you have just done that and not rebooted, do that next.

When promoting other DCs, ensure that the PDC is in the new DC's network settings as the primary DNS server.

Without more information about your environment or what you're actually doing, it's very difficult to provide advice.